# Prolog insert element issue

Tags: list, prolog

So I have Prolog code to insert an element at a given position:

```
ins(Val, [H|List], Pos, [H|Res]):-
   Pos > 1,
   !, 
   Pos1 is Pos - 1, 
   ins(Val, List, Pos1, Res). 
ins(Val, List, 1, [Val|List]).
```

This gives an output

```
28 ?- ins(B, [A,C,D], 4, Z).
Z = [A, C, D, B].
```

which works fine.

Now I wanted to reuse this code at the start at the list.

```
addFirst(Val, [H|List], [H|Res]):-
   ins(Val, [H|List], 1, [H|Res]).
```

This gives me an output

```
41 ?- addFirst(A, [B,C,D], Z).
A = B,
Z = [B, B, C, D].
```

Can someone please help me why this happens? I'm new to Prolog.

Comment: It would be helpful if you made sure that your casing is right. Variables begin with an upper-case letter and atoms a lower-case letter. Everything you have is upper-case. No wonder things don't work. Can you fix your code please?

Comment: @Enigmativity the case is part of the bug; fixing the code in this respect would reveal the nature of the bug to the OP but change the meaning of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you face is that your code doesn't properly reflect your intentions.

```
addFirst(Value, List, Result) :-
   ins(Value, List, 1, Result).
```

If you want to add a value as the first of a list, insert it into the list at position 1. That is what the above statement says and that's all that is needed.

---

The bug you notice stems from two mistakes.

The first is your rule for `addFirst`.

```
addFirst(Val,[H|List],[H|Res]):-
   ins(Val,[H|List],1,[H|Res]).
```

This states that the heads of both list should be the same. In other words, you have a list `[H|List]`, you add `Val` in the first position, and you expect the outcome to be `[H|Res]`. The only way this can occur is when the value to be added is the head of the list it's being added to.

And here is where the second mistake comes into play.

```
41 ?- addFirst(A,[B,C,D],Z).
A = B,
Z = [B, B, C, D].
```

You are using upper-case letters. Upper-case letters indicate variables. So the Prolog interpreter tries to assign values to those variables in a way to make `addFirst(A,[B,C,D],Z)` true. As we've just seen, that must mean the head of the list must be equal to the value that's added, so `A = B`, which is the first part of the reply. The second part is resulting list, which is the list (consisting of *variables*!) `[B, B, C, D]`.

Had you used lower-case letters for your list and the new element, this query would've failed.

```
41 ?- addFirst(a,[b,c,d],Z).
No.
```

Comment: I really liked the solution and the explanation. Cleared a lot in my head. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

the bug is an undue sharing of H... less verbose is better: this works

```
addFirst(Val,List,Res):-
    ins(Val,List,1,Res).
```

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at nth[0,1]/4 :

```
 ?- nth0(3, R, z, [a,b,c] ).
R = [a, b, c, z].
```

It could be helpful.

Comment: I knew about that but I needed to implement it myself. Thanks though